# use convert statement in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

here im doing something like this in my repository to fetch the data where data in `HasSet` :

```
List<MessageCampain>findAllByCampCdIn(Set<String> campCd);
```

my oracle database encoded with `ISO 8859-6`i just need it to be `UTF-8` to be more precisely i need to column in my pojo `messageBody` as `utf-8` how can i achieve that ?

repository :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sms_message_lookup")
public class MessageCampain {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROWID")
    private String rowid;

    @Column(name = "camp_cd")
    private String campCd;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "sms_body")
    private String messageBody;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "modified")
    private Date modified;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "last_modified_by_user")
    private String lastModifiedByUser;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "created_by_user")
    private String createdByUser;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "sms_language")
    private String smsLanguage;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "when_send_sms")
    private String whenSendSms;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "to_be_delayed")
    private String toBeDelayed;

    @Column(nullable = true, name = "flash_sms_flag")
    private String flashSmsFlag;
```

repository :

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageCampain, Long> {
    List<MessageCampain>findAllByCampCdIn(Set<String> campCd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is capable of encoding any Unicode code point. ISO-8859-1 can handle only a tiny fraction of them. So, transcoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 is no problem.

you can try below example:

```
// Create the encoder and decoder for ISO-8859-1
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

try {
    // Convert a string to ISO-LATIN-1 bytes in a ByteBuffer
    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("a string"));

    // Convert ISO-LATIN-1 bytes in a ByteBuffer to a character ByteBuffer and then to a string.
    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
    String s = cbuf.toString();
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
}
```

Comment: i have tried it , it does work, returns null value in all cases

Comment: try to debug it, why you are getting null